# how can I apply a formula for each row

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, sapply

I have data like this

```
df<-structure(list(data = structure(c(8L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0", 
"2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0", 
"2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0", 
"2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0", 
"2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0", 
"3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0", 
"M1yrtr", "Mitered"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to calculate the following for each row

for example for the second row which is

```
2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

I want to calculate this

```
n =5
(-(2/n)*log2(2/n)) + (-(1/n)*log2(1/n)) +(-(1/n)*log2(1/n))+ (-(1/n)*log2(1/n))
```

for the third one which is

```
2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

I will calculate this

```
(-(2/n)*log2(2/n)) + (-(2/n)*log2(2/n)) + (-(1/n)*log2(1/n))
```

so the output looks like this

```
dfout<- structure(list(data = structure(c(8L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0", 
"2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0", 
"2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0", 
"2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0", 
"2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0", 
"3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0", 
"M1yrtr", "Mitered"), class = "factor"), X = structure(c(8L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L), .Label = c("0.2604594", 
"1.03563", "1.168964", "2.020935", "2.077468", "2.204594", "M1yrtr", 
"Mitered"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R all basic operations (addition subtraction, multiplication, logarithms,...) are vectorized. This means that  for example if `x` is a vector then `log(x)` is just the componentwise `log` function, ore `1 / x` is just component wise division.

Therefore, you can do the following:

```
x <- as.numeric(str_split(df[2, ], ", ", simplify = T))
n <- 5
sum((-(x[x > 0]/n)*log2(x[x > 0]/n)))
[1] 1.921928
```

If you want to apply this for all rows you can use the `sapply` function like this:

```
myfun <- function(x){
 if (! grepl(",", x)) return(as.character(x))
  n <- 5
  y <- as.numeric(str_split(x, ", ", simplify = T))
  as.character(sum((-(y[y > 0]/n)*log2(y[y > 0]/n))))
}

df$newcol <- sapply(df[,1], myfun)
```

Comment: I am more interested in doing it more programmatically. if I want to use your method, It will be the same as I am doing it one y one. is there a way to get an output like what I showed above ?

Comment: I added a way to do this for the whole data.frame

Comment: thank you so much for your time but still what you calculate is different than what I calculated above

Comment: the values in `dfout` do not match the formula you have provided.
For example:`(-(2/n)*log2(2/n)) + (-(1/n)*log2(1/n)) +(-(1/n)*log2(1/n))+ (-(1/n)*log2(1/n))`  =  1.921928. 
But in `dfout` you have 1.168964

Comment: I think I got enough of your time, I will try to figure that out. Thanks a bunch. I liked and accepted your answer